# for line in open paradigm python

Tags: python, file-io, warnings

I always read files in Python like this:

```
for line in open('filename'):
    pass
```

Recently, python started spewing this warnings:

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='filename' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

What is the pythonic way of reading every line in a file, without this kind of warnings?

```
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
```

Feels like a line (and indentation level) too much.

Comment: I prefer the `with open...` way, but if you like you can always `for line in open('filename').readlines():`

Comment: Using `with` you dont have to close file manually, it will close automatically. If you use your way then you have to close file.

Comment: It may feel like a line too much, but the `with` statement opens a new context, in which the file is open. When the context closes (using the indentation) the file is closed automagically preventing resources left open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cleaning up when using exceptions and files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149983/cleaning-up-when-using-exceptions-and-files-in-python)